# NetBeans is not creating folder in localhost XAMPP for php project in Mac

Tags: php, macos, netbeans, xampp, directory

I am starting to work in PHP project with NetBeans and XAMPP. I am using the option "Copy files from Sources Folder to another location" to have he files available in my local host. The problem I am facing is NetBeasn is not creating any folder but it is not giving any message error. 
I have followed the instructions in NetBeans site and also I have performed some searching in internet to find a solution but nothing is working.

- I have checked the correct project settings, and if I try to create a folder in a differet directory (for example Docuements) NetBeasn create the folder without any problem.
- I have reviewed the folder permissions and these are ok too. Also I have changed the settings for the subfolders.

Any one have a clue to solve this issue?

I am using NetBeans 8, OS X Maverick

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Project Properties in NetBeans and check "Copy files on project open". Then "run project" from NetBeans.
This might solve the problem